# Combine multiple power supplies with shared negative

Tags: power-supply, power, dual, dual-supply

I have a computer power supply that supplies 24V, 12V and 5V. The 24V rail is dead but all other outputs work. (I need to figure out what's busted).

Can I add a 24V power supply alongside the existing one? Is there any problem with having the existing PSU and the new one (black wire) connected to negative from BOTH PSUs?

Yellow wire is 24V. Black wires are negative. As per the manual, it says all negatives are "shared":

[image]

[image]

Pic of the plan:

[image]

Comment: That should work just fine as long as it can supply enough current. Just leave the 24V output from the joriginal power supply open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming your new 24V supply has an isolated output, you can disconnect the exiting 24 wire connect a new one and share the negative.  Electrically that will be fine.

However you may find that your device needs the 24V to turn or before or after the 5V comes on.  If that's the case there's a potential for the device to be damaged.